# Making a calculator but no way to retrieve functions

Tags: android, string, parsing, integer, calculator

An easy way to make an android calculator would be to have 3 separate edit text boxes and have the user in put a number, a function, and then another number like 3 + 3. This would make it easier for the app dev to store the number(s) and function(s) and perform a calculation.

Now... my calculator app has the ability to out put all the input real-time, the down side is that when I retrieve what's in the input box, i retrieve it as string (to make sure i include all the functions input-ed). I know how to retrieve numbers (by using int parse) but how do I retrieve the functions such as + - / * ? (They're the main bit!! :O). Any help would me much appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a switch that analyze and identify the correct operation. Something like this:
(I suppose the content of function EditText in a string named functionSign

```
...
switch(functionSign)
{
case "+": return op1+op2;
case "-": return op1-op2;
...
```

EDIT 2:
I suppose that user can put only the functions simbols + - / * and the operations are organized in a method:

```
public double calculate()
{
  String operations= inputEditText.getText().toString();
  StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(operations); 
  //to calculate in input must have at last one operation and two operands
  //the first token must be a number (the operation scheme is (number)(function)(numeber)...)
  double result=Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
  while(st.hasMoreTokens())
  {
    String s=st.nextToken();

    if(s.equals("+")) 
       result += Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
    else if(s.equals("-"))
       result -= Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
    else if(s.equals("*"))
       result *= Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
    else if(s.equals("/"))
       result /= Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
    else
       throw new Exception();
  }
  return result;
}
```

This code is a really simple example, you must be sure that the user don't try to calculate something incomplete like:

- 3 + 3 -
- / 3 * 5

and similar. What the user should be able to do is your decision

Comment: but what if there's something like 4+6-11+10-14?

Comment: Clarify to me one thing: how the user insert the operation? You talked about 3 EditText so I suppose that the user can insert one operation at a time.

Comment: nope, i've done it so that as soon as the user inserts a number/function it instantly gets displayed on the screen in 1 edit text box (so only one place of input)

Comment: It's not so clear for me how you organized the user input. He have the 3 EditText, two for operands and one for the function? When I put, for example, 3 + 3 on the three EditText the calculate this operation or what happen? My answer depend on this organization

Comment: @user3470343 One place of input, so I suppose the user put number or function and you stack them in a string while it put in. Your problem is in showing it or in calculating it? I suppose in this last case because to show the string the user put istantly shouldn't is a problem. You want to calculate partial result as the user put infos?

Comment: @user3470343 I can propose you to use a StringTokenizer in this way: every time the user put a number/simbol put a whitespace between the elements in the EditText. When you retrive the string from it use the StringTokenizer to read one by one numbers and functions. Do it in a for and use an if statement in it to understand if you are reading a number or one of the function simbol you want the user can put.

Comment: I don't know if you saw it, but I edited the main comment to show you a structure not complete of the code. If you want something more complete just tell me.

Comment: It makes sense but I guess you could add more to be slightly clearer. Thanks once again :)

Comment: I understand most of the code, but could you explain what the 'nextToken()' and 'hasMoreTokens()' methods do?

Comment: Have you ever used StringTokenizer? Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the operator as a string and use if statements to determine what to do:

```
    String operator=operatorEditText.getText().toString();

    if (operator.equals("+")){
      //addition code here
    }
    else if (operator.equals("-")){
      //subtraction code here
    }
    ...
```

Comment: That's how I've done it, so if the user adds, I get what's already in the output box eg (8+7+8+2+3), and stick a + on the end...(8+7+8+2+3+) It gets retrieved/stored as a string though?